# Rigid body hitboxes

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to get a ball to land into a bowl but instead it just kinda balances on to like if there's some kind of invisible plane on to of the ball. My best guess would be hitboxes. Does anyone know how to fix this?[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Make the rigid body collisions shape of your bowl, **mesh** rather than **convex hull**. A convex hull will not include concavities, eg the inside of your bowl.

Also, in edit mode hit space and look for recalculate normals. If your normals are funky, the hitbox will be too.